# Dynamic Column lookup with different pages in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a multi page spread sheet in excel that needs to read information dynamically from columns on other pages and have these values show up on a main page.

This is the formula I'm using:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($B:$B,'CP01'!$B:$BN,3,FALSE)="r","r",
        IF(VLOOKUP($B:$B,'CP01'!$B:$BN,3,FALSE)="a","a",""))
```

`CP01` is a sheet in the excel file and instead of look at the specific sheet I want it to look at all of the sheets in the file.

Is there a way to do this as an excel formula or with excel-VBA?

Edit: I also tried `CP*` (* being a wildcard character) and it didn't work.

Edit2: Is there a way to match the value where the 'CP' is placed with its a other columns value?

Comment: still don't really understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: 'CP01' is a hard coded value in this formula. However, it need to change values when with the column it corresponds to. So if column A says 'CP02' then where the values in the formula in column B need to change to that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place this function in a `VBA` module:

```
Public Function sheetName(index As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
    sheetName = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(index).Name
    sheetName = IIf(Err.Number = 0, sheetName, CVErr(xlErrNA))
End Function
```

then you can do things like this (column `B` shows value of column `A`):

[image]

So now referring to a cell from another sheet is like this (column `B` shows value of column `A`):

[image]

I hope this helps?

Comment: This helps and makes since, but I need the value of cell A to go into a formula in cell B. Can I do this with this module?

Comment: Yes: change this part `'CP01'!$B:$BN` with `INDIRECT(sheetName(1) &"!$B:$BN")` in your code, assuming that `CP01` is your first sheet. If `CP01` is your second sheet, use `sheetName(2)` instead. To automate scanning all sheets, start your formula from row 1, and as you drag it down `sheetName(ROW())` will be giving you the name of the `ROW()`-th sheet in your file.